# Async call + event + dispatcher = unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, dispatcher

I have a *mysterious* problem, which I can't reproduce on my PC, but it happens on other PCs.

Here is a *simplified cut* which shows the problem

```
class SomeViewModel
{
    Item _item;
    Job _job = new Job();

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        _job.Progress += (s, e) => App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Progress());         
    }

    async void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
        SomeItem.SomeProperty = newValue; // this proves SomeItem is not null
        _item = SomeItem;
        var result = await Task<bool>.Run(() => _job.Do());
        _item = null;
        ...
    }

    void Progress()
    {
        if(_item == null) { ... } // sometimes true, why???
        ...
    }
}

class Job
{
    public event EventHandler Progress;

    public bool Do()
    {
        ...
        Progress?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); // in cycle
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

`DoSomething` is called from button command. Idea is to store current item in the field and access it within event handler. Event is never called **before** item is set to something and is never called **after** item is set to `null`.

My question: how is it possible for `_item == null` in event handler?

It will either never happens (my PC) or happens every time (other PC). And I can't understand what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Because you have `_item = null`...you are caught in a **race condition** in async programming.

Comment: @davidshen84, can you explain how exactly it happens please? I don't see the problem.

Comment: You set *item*, start a new thread to execute **Do**, then set *item = null*. When **Do** started to execute, *item* has already been set to **null**. Remember `item` is a reference.

Comment: @davidshen84, do you see `await` before? I set item, start a new **task** and await for it (task will run `Do()` synchronously and complete only when `Do()` return value). Only then item is set to `null` (for GC to clean item some times later). I can't imagine a single scenario when item is `null`. My question is basically what scenario should I check? What **can** go wrong to have that what is happening to happens?

Comment: Apparently _item variable value somehow is not synchronized between main and task threads. You may try to use volatile keyword to check this: volatile Item _item;

Comment: The code you posted *should* work. I'm wondering if there's a bug in an older version of the desktop framework on the other computer, or something odd like that.